# HeidiSQL like Windows software but WITH zip/gzip export and import ability. Is there any?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I like HeidiSQL software very much for its simplicity, however I miss the phpMyAdmin function for compress exported sql file directly into zip or gzip file.

In HeidiSQL I have to manually compress sql file in program like 7Zip after exporting from HeidiSQL.

Another bad thing is that I have to repeat the same process when importing zip files into HeidiSQL. In reverse order of course (unpack zip file and import row sql file).

It is not very convenient.

Is there any similar software like HeidiSQL (on the Windows platform) which can import/export zip/gzip files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to extract/backup data in Heidi as a big file with `.SQL` extension. That one is quite easy to access/read/edit in plain text editors and almost all GUI and command line database managers have implemented restore using those SQL dumps.

Comment: I have many backups, so it is difference for me 100MB sql file vs 10MB zip file. After a year I need to buy a new disc when I will refuse to compress my sql files. So, there is no software that is capable of doing this? Is phpMyAdmin really the only one that can compress and uncompress sql files?

Comment: My backups go near to 30 MiB as of yet. Bought new 500 GB HDD for the server. :)

Answer (score 0):

Today you can export directly to a compressed zip archive using HeidiSQL.

But for importing you still need to uncompress the file yourself before feeding it to HeidiSQL.

Alternatives to HeidiSQL include:

- Toad for MySQL Freeware
- MySQL Workbench
- Navicat

(Anyone who knows about zip/gzip support, feel free to make an edit.)